# RxSwift Observable that throws Error alternative to catchErrorJustReturn

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am seeking for alternative way to handle errors thrown through Observable sequence.

I have database request that frequently just throws DaoError.notFound (meaning data has not been found).

Then I am doing Remote API request that saves new data to database, and it should cause CoreData to emit new data through first Observable sequence. But it doesn't happen in spite of using RxCoreData. And the reason is that first Observable is terminated with Error.

I can use:

**catchErrorJustReturn([])** but it emits empty array of elements and completes Observable sequence, no more elements will be emitted via this sequence.

**retry()** but it hangs retrying which is also not perfect solution as when there is no elements I just want to display empty table view with no items.

The perfect solution will be just somehow mapping or errors to empty arrays but keep Observable stream alive. But it doesn't happen.

The simplest solution will be replacing DaoError.notFound with returning empty array, but it is odd that I cannot keep error and in some usage create infinite stream and ignore errors.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `catchError(_:)`

```
let myData = database.getData().catchError { _ in api.getData().startWith([]) }
```

### Additional code based on comment:

Here's a more involved example:

```
let myData = database.getData().catchError { _ in
    api.getData()
        .do(onNext: { database.saveData($0) })
        .startWith([])
}
```

The above will attempt to get the data from the database. If that fails, then it will emit an empty array and attempt to get the data from the API. If it gets new data then it will save the new data in the database and emit the new data.

The fundamental answer is still the same, use `catchError(_:)`.

Comment: I think it will not work. As I want to get data from data base if there are some data ok, it there are no data return empty array (change Error to this empty array), and make request for new data every time to refresh them, If this data are refreshed database stream should push this refreshed data. If I use my current solution error causes stream to be completed and refresh isn't pushed anymore. If I do your solution as I understand refresh will be done only if there are not data in database and has been error, and if there are cached old data they won't be refreshed.

Comment: I think it is better approach. And I can accept it. Of course is has drawback that as I understand I want have stream to database that will notify observer each time there are changes to those database request. Example I get data from database and have sequence that is refreshed later each time something changes via RxCoreData it is via NFFetchResultsController underneath. But here I have error handled in such way that if it occur then api request is made (it is previously returning [] empty array) and after it fetched data from api it just return them (now also saves in DB) but then completes

Comment: So there is no live stream to database after this request. Also what about situation that in database are old data from previous request. Then this code doesn't refresh cached data, as error doesn't happen and remote api want be called. 

As for now I have replaced throw DaoError.notFound with just returning empty array as I cannot conceive better solution that will handle error such that stream will continue to live and api request refresh data and notify observer via live database stream